# How to browserify jquery mobile and jquery module of NPM to work?

Tags: jquery-mobile, browserify

I want to develop mobile application with jquery mobile, the module available on NPM, not to include it in a script tag. And I want to use browserify to bundle all my js files including jquery mobile.

So I included the "bundle.js" in the index.html, I write some jqm pages on it, and I test it. The index.html isn't showing like a mobile application, just looks like regular web page with html elements laying on it.

It works if I include jquery and jquery mobile library in script tags.

What's the difference here, how should I make it work?

Comment: I am refraining from downvoting, Please ask one question. Not how to build a jquery mobile website.